# d3.js : re-inserting elements during dragstart/mousedown interferes with click events in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox

Tags: d3.js

I have run into a problem implementing both click and drag functionality on the same elements using d3.js...any help would be appreciated.  The problem described below occurs with Chrome and Safari, but not with Firefox.

### Some Background

When an element is dragged (at least with d3) the order of events is as follows:

- dragstart
- drag
- dragend
- click
- dblclick

Even if the element isn't actually dragged (and hence no drag events), the dragstart and dragend events still do fire (on mousedown and mouseup) with the click event occurring afterward.

### The Problem

I need to have both drag and click (and double-click) functionality on the same SVG elements.  When dragging an element, it is important to us for the element always to be layered above any other elements in a z-index sense (i.e. so that it doesn't get hidden by a sibling element while being dragged).  With SVG, elements that appear later in the DOM are layered above elements that appear earlier.  So, in order to guarantee that the drag element is always on top, I append the drag element as the last child of its parent during the execution of the dragstart event handler using:

```
elem.parentNode.appendChild(elem);
```

Unfortunately, this causes the click event not to fire in Chrome and Safari if the element in question was not the last child element to begin with (and hence was then appended into its new DOM location).  If the element started as the last child (or was appended there from a previous click), then the click event does fire on subsequent clicks.  The same kind of thing happens (in the absence of drag behavior) with mousedown and mouseup events, though this use case is not important to us.  Again, none of this is a problem in Firefox.

A further complication (too difficult to explain here) is that I also need to redraw the elements once the dragend event has completed, which also involves reordering the elements into their original DOM order.  So, even after an element has been clicked once, it never ends up as the last child once the dragend handler has finished executing.

### Demonstration

I have set up a demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb4e6sss/3/

The circles demonstrate the problem with drag behavior, and the squares demonstrate it with mousedown/mouseup handlers.  Clicking on a circle or square should toggle the shape's colors.  Notice that on Chrome and Safari, only the last circle or square fires the click event, while on Firefox they all do.

The JS code from the above demo is shown below:

```
var svg = d3.select('body > svg');

var radius = 30;

var circleData = [
    {
        position: { x: 90, y: 100 },
        value: 1
    },
    {
        position: { x: 220, y: 100 },
        value: 2
    },
    {
        position: { x: 350, y: 100 },
        value: 3
    }
];

var squareData = [
    {
        position: { x: 90, y: 350 },
        value: 4
    },
    {
        position: { x: 220, y: 350 },
        value: 5
    },
    {
        position: { x: 350, y: 350 },
        value: 6
    }
];

var setupCircles;
var setupSquares;

var reinsertElem = function (elem) {
    elem.parentNode.appendChild(elem);
};

var handleClick = function (d, i) {
    console.debug('clicked: ' + i);

    // Make lit on click only!!
    var shapeGroup = d3.select(this);
    var isLit = shapeGroup.classed('lit');
    shapeGroup.classed('lit', !isLit);
};

var handleMouseDown = function (d, i) {
    console.debug('mouseDown: ' + i);
    // Re-insert the clicked shape so that it appears on top of all other shapes
    reinsertElem(this);
};

var handleMouseUp = function (d, i) {
    console.debug('mouseUp: ' + i);
    setupSquares();
};

var originFn = function (d) {
    return d.position;
};

var dragStartFn = function (d, i) {
    console.debug('drag started: ' + i);
    // Prevent the event from bubbling up
    d3.event['sourceEvent'].stopPropagation();
    // Re-insert the drag shape so that it appears on top of all other shapes
    reinsertElem(this);
};

var dragFn = function (d, i) {
    // Constrain the drag position to keep the shape displayed in the rect area
    var newX = Math.max(radius, Math.min(600 - radius, d3.event.x));
    var newY = Math.max(radius, Math.min(250 - radius, d3.event.y));
    circleData[i].position = { x: newX, y: newY };
    d.position = { x: newX, y: newY };
    d3.select(this).attr('transform', function (d) { return 'translate(' + newX + ',' + newY + ')'; });
};

var dragEndFn = function (d, i) {
    console.debug('drag ended: ' + i);
    setupCircles();
};

var dragBehavior = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(originFn)
    .on('dragstart', dragStartFn)
    .on('drag', dragFn)
    .on('dragend', dragEndFn);

setupCircles = function () {
    var circlesGroup = svg.select('g.circles');
    var circleGroup = circlesGroup.selectAll('g')
        .data(circleData, function (d) { return d.value; });

    var circleGroupEnter = circleGroup.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', function (d, i) { return 'circle' + i; })
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
            var position = d.position;
            return 'translate(' + position.x + ',' + position.y + ')';
        })
        .on('click', handleClick)
        .call(dragBehavior);

    var circle = circleGroupEnter.append('circle')
        .classed('fill0', true)
        .classed('stroke1', true)
        .attr('stroke-width', '1px')
        .attr('r', radius.toString());

    var text = circleGroupEnter.append('text')
        .attr('font-family', 'Arial')
        .attr('font-size', '20px')
        .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text(function (d, i) { return d.value.toString(); });

    circleGroup.order();
};

setupSquares = function () {
    var squareWidth = radius * 2;
    var squaresGroup = svg.select('g.squares');
    var squareGroup = squaresGroup.selectAll('g')
        .data(squareData, function (d) { return d.value; });

    var squareGroupEnter = squareGroup.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', function (d, i) { return 'square' + i; })
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
            var positionX = d.position.x - (0.5 * squareWidth);
            var positionY = d.position.y - (0.5 * squareWidth);
            return 'translate(' + positionX + ',' + positionY + ')';
        })
        .on('click', handleClick)
        .on('mousedown', handleMouseDown)
        .on('mouseup', handleMouseUp);

    var square = squareGroupEnter.append('rect')
        .classed('fill0', true)
        .classed('stroke1', true)
        .attr('stroke-width', '1px')
        .attr('width', squareWidth.toString())
        .attr('height', squareWidth.toString());

    var text = squareGroupEnter.append('text')
        .attr('font-family', 'Arial')
        .attr('font-size', '20px')
        .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('x', function (d, i) { return (0.5 * squareWidth).toString(); })
        .attr('y', function (d, i) { return (0.5 * squareWidth).toString(); })
        .text(function (d, i) { return d.value.toString(); });

    squareGroup.order();
};

setupCircles();
setupSquares();
```

Any suggestions for how to get around this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact same problem. The solution was to:

- add a boolean var to act as flag to indicate re-insert is needed.
- in dragStartFn, set flag to true, and remove the re-insert bit from here.
- in dragFn, add a check at the top and if flag true then do the re-insert and set the flag false so that it only happens once.

This way for straight clicks the re-insert doesn't happen and the event is correctly triggered. Then for actual drags the re-insert still happens so you're all good there too.